# Как вывести информацию SQL в DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server, binding, datagrid

Хотел попробовать написать программу по правилам паттерна MVVM. Фактически я никогда не работал с ним.
Мне нужно связать SQL Server с WPF и вывести таблицу в `DataGrid`. Это у меня получилось.

НО! Я решил усложнить себе задачу и сделать за принципом паттерна.
И проблема заключается в том, что когда я инициализирую сами столбцы и не разрешаю автоматическую генерацию столбцов заполнение `DataGrid` — выдает пустую таблицу.

Я понимаю, что где-то в файле `MainViewModel` нужно прописать коллекцию работы с SQL, но не знаю как и сформулировать запрос в Google не могу правильно =)

Разметка XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="ShipmentGrid" Style="{StaticResource DataGridShipment}" ItemsSource="{Binding ShipmentList}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Организация"  Binding="{Binding Oraganization}" Width="100"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Город"        Binding="{Binding City}"          Width="100"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Страна"       Binding="{Binding Country}"       Width="100"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Менеджер"     Binding="{Binding Manager}"       Width="100"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Количество"   Binding="{Binding Quantity}"      Width="100"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Сумма за ед." Binding="{Binding AmountPerItem}" Width="100"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Общая сумма"  Binding="{Binding TotalAmount}"   Width="100"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Дата"         Binding="{Binding Data}"          Width="100"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Кастомизация `DataGrid`:

```
<Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False"></Setter>
```

В `Model` у меня храниться один файл (`Shipments`):

```
class Shipments
{
    public string Organization  { get; set; }
    public string City          { get; set; }
    public string Country       { get; set; }
    public string Manager       { get; set; }
    public int    Quantity      { get; set; }
    public double AmntPerInt    { get; set; }
    public double TotalAmount   { get; set; }
    public string Data          { get; set; }

    public Shipments(string Organization, string City, string Country, string Manager, 
                     int Quantity, double AmntPerInt, double TotalAmount, string Data)
    {
        this.Organization   = Organization;
        this.City           = City;
        this.Country        = Country;
        this.Manager        = Manager;
        this.Quantity       = Quantity;
        this.AmntPerInt     = AmntPerInt;
        this.TotalAmount    = TotalAmount;
        this.Data           = Data;
    }
}
```

А в папке `ViewModel` три файла:

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    public ObservableCollection<ShipmentViewModel> ShipmentList { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel(List<Shipments> shipments) {
        ShipmentList = new ObservableCollection<ShipmentViewModel>(shipments.Select(b => new ShipmentViewModel(b)));
    }
}

class ShipmentViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    public Shipments Shipments;

    public ShipmentViewModel(Shipments shipments) {
        this.Shipments = shipments;
    }

    public string Organization {
        get { return Shipments.Organization; }
        set
        {
            Shipments.Organization = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Организация");
        }
    } // и дальше каждый столбец
}
```

Comment: Первое, не забыли DataContext окна указать? если дело происходит в Codebehind окна, то обязательно нужно DataContext= this;

Comment: Второе, меня смущает ваше OnPropertyChanged("Организация");

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас буду разбираться с DataContext. А почему Вас смущает OnPropertyChanged("Организация")? Что с этим не так? Я смотрел разные примеры, писали так же)

Comment: с onpropertychanged лучше  использовать nameof(свойство). Если вы пишете "Организация" значит есть свойство с таким же именем, а это странно. Можно еще использовать атрибут PropertychangedInvocator из набора решарпера, тогда при вызове не надо будет вообще ничего не передавать в параметре

Comment: почитайте Адам Натан Wpf подробное руководство. Ответы на все вопросы найдете там.